# Do a need a comma when while is used in this way?

Tags: punctuation

In the example that I'm going to provide and write here, is a comma needed where I put it?

> While reading this book, I found out the events happen in the story have similarities with our present situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'While reading this book, I found out the events happen in the story
>   have similarities with our present situation.'

"While reading this book" - this portion is called dependent clause of the sentence. For this reason, a comma after book is grammatically correct. Next part of the sentence is independent clause. if you write independent clause at the beginning of the sentence, then the comma is not necessary. hope you find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

'While reading this book, I found out the events happen in the story have similarities with our present situation.'

Yes you need a comma because the first one is a separate clause. You will also notice that you pause after finishing the first sentence.

Comment: thanks, and what about when while is omitted in the same sentence?

Comment: @mana, why would you omit while?

Comment: it's possible, right? anyway i just wanna know about the punctuation so i won't make any mistakes in my advanced writing course.

Comment: @mana, your punctuation is right